# How to change background image on Vimeo Portfolio Collections

Tags: css, background-color, vimeo

I'm trying to change the background color to just black on this site: https://vimeopro.com/mbtv11/our-short-film-show. I have this code so far, but I can't get the wrapper to go away. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

div {
background-color: #000000
}

Comment: Like this? https://nimb.ws/rwfeUK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post the actual code and not a link.

.wrapper .content has a background image. You need to remove it with the snippet below, or override it with !important.

```
.wrapper .content { background: transparent; }
```